# How can I use the product/list template in my module?

Tags: module, blocks, template, magento-1, product-list

I have an **own module to listing products using the product list template**. So my call in cms block is:

```
{{block type="XX/XX" name="XX" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

In my block code I use this function:

```
public function getProducts() 
{
    $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('XX',array('eq' => 1))
        ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
        ->setPageSize(10);

    $this->setProductCollection($products);

    return $products;
}
```

But it isn't working. What is the problem?

#### Edit:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $arr_products = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel("mycode/mycode")->getProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $arr_products[] = array(
            'id' => $product->getId(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
        );
    }

    return $arr_products;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your `XX/XX` please ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: what class is your block class extending ?

Comment: "Mage_Core_Block_Template". This is ok because I tried this with my own phtml file and It's work perfectly but I want to use the default template: catalog/product/list.phtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I reckon the problem here is that you are extending `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and the default template uses a lot of methods declared in the native block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

My advice is to make your block extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`, this way the native template you want to use will benefit from all the native methods.

Then, instead of creating a `getProducts()` method I reckon you will have to override the `_getProductCollection()` method which is called by the template to retrieve the products.

Comment: And the model class? Has it to extend from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List ??

Comment: @philips_te which model ? If you're referring to the one from `Mage::getModel("mycode/mycode")` you don't need to modify it. You just need to use collections, I reckon you should have a look at the original `_getProductCollection` from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` and base your development on it ;)

Comment: Fantastic!! It is working perfectly! :D

Comment: @philips_te feel free to mark your question as accepted so others will benefit from it ;)